# can an algorithm be a single instruction?

Tags: algorithm, definition

The most common definition of the word **algorithm** is:

> "An algorithm is a finite ordered set of unambiguous **instructions**"

is it correct to say

> "An algorithm is a finite ordered set of unambiguous **instructions/instruction**"

simply can an **algorithm be a single instruction ?**

Answer (score 2):

The definition you quote says that an algorithm is a *"finite ordered set"*, which not only would allow an algorithm to be a single instruction (i.e. a set with one element), it even allows for an algorithm to have **no** instructions (i.e. an empty set).

That said, we shouldn't take *"finite ordered set"* too literally, because a set cannot have repeated elements, whereas an algorithm can have repeated instructions. Also, there can be multiple different "implementations" of the "same" algorithm which would not strictly be the exact same ordered set of instructions; see for example [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Bubble_sort) which lists many different implementations of the bubble sort algorithm, which are all different "sets of instructions" in a strict mathematical sense, but they are the same "algorithm" in the sense normally understood by programmers and computer scientists.

So the real answer is, an algorithm can be a single instruction if you define the word "algorithm" to allow that, and most definitions either allow it, don't specifically exclude it, or aren't meant to be strict mathematical definitions anyway.

<sub>As a grammatical note, it is not necessary to say *"set of instructions/instruction"* in order to include the possibility that the set has size 1; you would have to say *"set of at least two instructions"* if you wanted to exclude that possibility.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Arguably yes, for example you may have an algorithm which add two values (or more interestingly [vectors of values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD)?)

This may be both one instruction in your programming language and also backed in the processor by a single instruction!

The processor may do a great deal of work to perform the instruction (and would certainly have an algorithm of its own to do so!), but there would only be one *instruction* to it.

---

There is, however, some haziness with how you define such a thing (so I wouldn't worry too much about it), for example if you compile for a custom processor (like one written to an [FPGA board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array)), you could make your own instruction with tremendous algorithmic complexity backing it.

.. or on a logical processor (such as the famous [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)) or intermediate representation (such as [LLVM IR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_representation)), you may have cases where one instruction in code becomes a collection of instructions on the logical system, but is then backed by a single operation on a modern processor (I do not know of real cases of this, but it certainly occurs with LLVM)

Answer (score 0):

In that case you would usually just call it an instruction, but I suppose that would also be correct. At the end of the day it's just a matter of interpretation, like asking if water is wet.